# How to use an attribute in the subclass and not the one from the extended abstract class?

Tags: java, setter

I want you use the method `setSalary` in this subclass, but I don't know how. It keeps printing out the default value which I initialized in the superclass.

**Superclass code:**

```
public abstract class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String ssn;
    protected double salary;

    public Employee (String n,String s){
        this.name=n;
        this.ssn=s;
        this.salary=0;

    }

    public abstract void setSalary(double salary);


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee Name: " + name + ", with social security number: " + ssn;
    }


}
```

**Subclass code:***

```
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
    private int hours;
    private int rate;

    public HourlyEmployee(int hours, int rate, String n, String s) {
        super(n, s);
        this.hours = hours;
        this.rate = rate;

    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = rate*hours;
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+ "\n"+ "Number of working hours is " +hours+ " and the rate per hour is" + rate + "\n"+" Employee salary is: " +salary +"$";

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the setter method?

Comment: I want to call it from the toString overrided method. how can I?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You should include a class with a `main()` method to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At

```
public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = rate*hours;
}
```

You are multiplying the default values which you set in the super class but not using the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing the value before calling the setter method. Try to call it first and then make the `toString` call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the HourlyEmployee object using constructor,
2. Call the setSalary method on the object,
3. Now, toString method should return right value

Answer (score 0):

In the first time, the salary property of the super class is initialized by the 0 value in the super constructor which is always called when you create the subclass instance, so you need to call setSalary method just after you created the instance of subclass to rectify the value of salary property and before you use it in the next of your code.